# How can I extract the ground from a DTM?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, filter

I need to create a shapefile that only includes the vegetation in the scene. I was thinking I could take the DTM and the DSM and subtract the DSM from the DTM. Is there a way to do this in ArcMAP?

Comment: Isn't the DTM the ground, and so you need to subtract the DTM from the DSM?

Answer (score 4):

The [Raster Calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm) can be used for band math such as this. You would use an expression like the following:

```
float("DSM") - float("DTM")
```